# Why do some monthly bond ETFs have no dividend in January?

Tags: bonds, dividends, bond-etf

For example, the following bond ETFs have monthly dividends except in January:

1) https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/funds-and-etfs/vteb/dividend-history:

```
                            ------------ DATES -------------- 
EX DATE     TYPE    AMOUNT  DECLARE    RECORD     PAYMENT 
12/23/2019  Cash    $0.099  12/20/2019  12/24/2019  12/27/2019
11/01/2019  Cash    $0.101  10/30/2019  11/04/2019  11/06/2019
[snip]
03/01/2019  Cash    $0.097  02/28/2019  03/04/2019  03/06/2019
02/01/2019  Cash    $0.107  01/31/2019  02/04/2019  02/06/2019
12/24/2018  Cash    $0.103  12/21/2018  12/26/2018  12/28/2018
11/01/2018  Cash    $0.107  10/30/2018  11/02/2018  11/06/2018
[snip]
02/01/2018  Cash    $0.089  01/30/2018  02/02/2018  02/06/2018
12/26/2017  Cash    $0.089  12/21/2017  12/27/2017  12/29/2017
11/01/2017  Cash    $0.08   10/30/2017  11/02/2017  11/06/2017
[snip]
03/01/2017  Cash    $0.083  02/28/2017  03/03/2017  03/07/2017
02/01/2017  Cash    $0.073  02/01/2017  02/03/2017  02/07/2017
12/22/2016  Cash    $0.078  12/21/2016  12/27/2016  12/29/2016
12/01/2016  Cash    $0.082  11/30/2016  12/05/2016  12/07/2016
11/01/2016  Cash    $0.063  10/31/2016  11/03/2016  11/07/2016
```

2) https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/funds-and-etfs/cmf/dividend-history

```
                            ------------ DATES -------------- 
EX DATE     TYPE    AMOUNT  DECLARE     RECORD     PAYMENT 
12/19/2019  Cash    $0.096  12/17/2018  12/20/2019  12/26/2019
11/01/2019  Cash    $0.101  12/17/2018  11/04/2019  11/07/2019
[snip]
02/01/2019  Cash    $0.106  12/17/2018  02/04/2019  02/07/2019
12/18/2018  Cash    $0.108  12/30/2017  12/19/2018  12/24/2018
11/01/2018  Cash    $0.113  12/30/2017  11/02/2018  11/07/2018
[snip]
03/01/2018  Cash    $0.11               03/02/2018  03/07/2018
02/01/2018  Cash    $0.101  01/31/2018  02/02/2018  02/07/2018
12/21/2017  Cash    $0.096  12/20/2017  12/22/2017  12/28/2017
11/01/2017  Cash    $0.102  10/31/2017  11/02/2017  11/07/2017
[snip]
03/01/2017  Cash    $0.22   03/01/2017  03/03/2017  03/07/2017
02/01/2017  Cash    $0.204  02/01/2017  02/03/2017  02/07/2017
12/22/2016  Cash    $0.192  12/22/2016  12/27/2016  12/29/2016
12/01/2016  Cash    $0.206  12/01/2016  12/05/2016  12/07/2016
11/01/2016  Cash    $0.199  11/01/2016  11/03/2016  11/07/2016
```

Comment: The ex-dividend date for stocks and ETFs that pay monthly dividends is toward the end of each month. You cited two examples that do  not.  Google "Monthly ETF dividends" and I bet that you'll find some that go ex-div in January.

Comment: @BobBaerker yes I'm not claiming that this affects all bond ETFs.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Comment: It wasn't me but it's likely that  your question wasn't up to their standards.

Comment: @BobBaerker I wonder which standards they have in mind.

Comment: In final analysis, does it really matter if an anonymous stranger on the internet downvoted your question?

Comment: @BobBaerker yes because it reduces the odds of someone answering the question, and also I'm genuinely curious if there is some amiss in my question

Comment: Why the down votes? I think because the question (which I've edited) was poorly worded, and heavy on links while being light on examples from the links.  Add example data from the links, and I think it'll be an excellent question.

Comment: @RonJohn thanks for the feedback and for the edit, I added the data to the question.

Comment: Sometimes -- but not always -- they have two dividends in December.

Comment: You used the phrase "affects all bond ETFs".  What "affect" is there if a dividend is declared, goes ex-div or is paid in January or early February?

Comment: @BobBaerker the choice of word was unfortunate, I just meant that some bond ETFs may have a dividend in January.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be why is the December dividend payment late and there is none in January?

Comment: OK, some bond ETFs might not pay a dividend in January.  Or behind curtain #2 is  why is the December dividend payment late and there is none in January? Once that is settled, what difference does it make?  You own it, you get the dividend.

Comment: @BobBaerker it's sometimes interesting to understand the products we own.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep that might be indeed more precise, but with the level of hypercriticality I'm receiving on this question I'm afraid some might argue it is not late because it was scheduled as such.